# Pulsating ring animation with CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-animations

I want to have an expanding radius that starts from the center of the `div` instead of it starting on the top left of the `div`.

Imagine the button has a pulsing outline that goes outwards. That pulsing outline should start from the middle of the `div` and go out.

See example here: https://jsbin.com/dinehoqaro/edit?html,css,output

You can see that the expansion is starting from the top left.

```css
.circle {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  animation: pulse 1s infinte;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1.2s infinite;
}
button {
  background-color: green;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  from {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  to {
    width: 100px height: 100px;
  }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  from {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  to {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"><button>click here</button></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a general solution using CSS [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) and [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter).

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.sphere {
  display: flex;
  background: lightblue;
  border-radius: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#container::after {
  display: flex;
  background: lightpink;
  border-radius: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  animation: pulsate 2.5s ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0.0;
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
@keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="sphere"></div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52grpf7L/12/)

Also see this awesome solution by [@harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry): [How to create a pulsing glow ring animation in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36707159/3597276)

Comment: This is exactly what im looking for! Is using flexbox the only solution? i would need it to support older broswers

Comment: The flexboxes are used for easy centering. You can also center using traditional methods. Here's a quick outtine using positioning properties (flexboxes removed): http://jsfiddle.net/52grpf7L/2/