# How to create a pulsing glow ring animation in CSS?

Tags: css, css-animations, visual-web-developer

I like the way this [website](http://emcsecurity.com/) made their rings glow and pulse out and would like to know how they did it.

I can make something similar but I'm not very good.

So this is all I was able to figure out but it doesn't seem to work.

CSS:

```
glowycircleouter.blue .glow4 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px #287ec6;
}
.glowycircleouter .glow4 {
  -webkit-animation: glowyglow 3s 2250ms infinite;
  -moz-animation: glowyglow 3s 2250ms infinite;
  -ms-animation: glowyglow 3s 2250ms infinite;
  -o-animation: glowyglow 3s 2250ms infinite;
  animation: glowyglow 3s 2250ms infinite;
  animation-name: glowyglow;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: initial;
  animation-delay: 2250ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: initial;
  animation-fill-mode: initial;
  animation-play-state: initial;
}
.glowycircleouter .glow4 {
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<span class="glow4"></span>
```

Comment: From looking at their source code, it looks like they used `keyframes`, `border-radius: 50%`, `opacity`, `transform`, `translate`, and `scale`.

Comment: Googling 'css pulsating rings' returns a stack of codepens and things: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyharry/dw51cgu6/

Comment: maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33160848/3597276

Comment: Are you looking for something like that http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/leaky-coffee-mug

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The threads linked in comments are helpful but I don't think this is an exact duplicate because this one is slightly more complex due to the need for multiple rings.

We can create this effect by animating `transform: scale()` and `opacity` of the elements. Here, we need more than 1 element because in the linked website we can see atleast 3 rings at any given point of time (one which is fading-in, one which is at its peak, one which is fading-out). By adding the same animation to two pseudo-elements, an inner element (the `span`) and by delaying the animation on two of them we can achieve the required  animation effect.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 50px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
div:before,
div:after, span {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #287ec6;
  animation: glow-grow 2s ease-out infinite;
}
div:after {
  animation-delay: .66s;
}
span{
  animation-delay: 1.33s;
  }
@keyframes glow-grow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, if using not infinite animation `animation: 6s ease-out 0s 1 glow-grow;`, how possible to remove stucked wawes after the end of animation?